# How to restrict access to file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I use the htaccess file on my ColdFusion server? I do not know how to use htaccess on my ColdFusion server to prevent direct access to files of attachment folder.

I am using ColdFusion 10 and have source code in the root directory of the ColdFusion server. I want to restrict direct access to files that are available in the Attachment folder. I placed two files inside this Attachment folder: `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

**. htaccess:**

```
AuthUserFile "/StagingTicketSystem/Attachments/.htpasswd" 
AuthName "Please Log In" AuthType Basic <Limit GET POST> required vaid-user </Limit>
```

**.htpasswd:**

```
admin:1234 root:4321
```

Comment: The htaccess file is used by the web server, not ColdFusion. That file has nothing to do with ColdFusion. It is processed by your web server before anything is handed off to ColdFusion.

Comment: may you please help.

Comment: i want to prevent direct access of file from attachment folder by using htaccess file,

Comment: I tried updating your question but we really need more details in order to help you. As it is currently written it is likely to be closed. What web server are you using? What does your folder layout look like? What files/folders are you trying to restrict? How do you want them protected/hidden? Perhaps most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using coldfusion10, i have source code in root directory of coldfusion server. want to restrict direct access to file that are available in Attachment folder. I placed two files inside this attachment folder: .htaccess and .htpasswd

Comment: . htacsess contain following codes:                                              AuthUserFile "/StagingTicketSystem/Attachments/.htpasswd"
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic       <Limit GET POST>
required vaid-user
</Limit>
.htpasswd contain following codes:                                                              admin:1234
root:4321